# A javascript design pattern for options with default values?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, optional-parameters

```
// opt_options is optional
function foo(a, b, opt_options) {
  // opt_c, opt_d, and opt_e are read from 'opt_options', only c and d have defaults
  var opt_c = 'default_for_c';
  var opt_d = 'default_for_d';
  var opt_e; // e has no default

  if (opt_options) {
    opt_c = opt_options.c || opt_c;
    opt_d = opt_options.d || opt_d;
    opt_e = opt_options.e;
  }
}
```

The above seems awfully verbose. What's a better way to handle argument options with default parameters?

Comment: jQuery and underscore both come with an extend method which handles this pretty well.

Comment: @blockhead - so, use `extend` and don't keep local variables for the options?

Comment: Actually, after a while I concluded that being verbose is *a good thing* when it comes to Javascript named arguments. Copying each argument to a variable at the start of the function is a good way to document what are the expected options and also lets you modify them without screwing with the original object.

Comment: @missingno - I tend to agree, but I don't like each variable appearing twice. Check out my solution below.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Now that I think about it, I kind of like this:

```
function foo(a, b, opt_options) {
  // Force opt_options to be an object
  opt_options = opt_options || {};

  // opt_c, opt_d, and opt_e are read from 'opt_options', only c and d have defaults
  var opt_c = 'default_for_c' || opt_options.c;
  var opt_d = 'default_for_d' || opt_options.d;
  var opt_e = opt_options.e; // e has no default
}
```

Comment: To continue our discussion... I also used to think like this, since I am a diehard code-duplication hater, but I changed my mind. I realized that I would often forget what options are accepted (and would have to search the function code to find out). Then II started adding comments to list the named arguments and then I moved on to just copying all the variables, treating all of them the same. While it is a little longer to type, it doesn't suffer from comment rot and it is more flexible (I can rename the variables inside the function, I can easily add and remove default values and so on...).

Comment: @missingno - I'm not sure I follow. In this answer I do copy the variables into variables, and this won't suffer from code rot. I just don't repeat them _twice_.

Comment: I am terribly sorry, the lack of `opt_a` and `opt_b` completely threw me off :)

Comment: Well, they're not _opt_ional :)

Comment: Should that not be `var opt_c = opt_options.c || 'default_for_c';` Doesn't seem like `opt_options.c` would ever be reached since `'default_for_c'` will evaluate as truthy.

Comment: @Sukima  Another problem is what if opt_options.c is set to false, it would then be changed back to true, which is not intended. It's probably better to  explicitly check for undefined in this case.

Comment: @RaySuelzer, agreed. something like: `var opt_c = opt_options.c != null ? opt_options.c : 'default_for_c';`

Comment: you'd want to use undefined since a null value must be explicitly declared as null in javascript.

Answer (score 91):

This uses [jQuery.extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) but could be interchanged with an object merger from your library of choice or Object.assign in ES6.

```
function Module(options){
    var defaults = {
        color: 'red'
    };
    var actual = $.extend({}, defaults, options || {});
    console.info( actual.color );
}

var a = new Module();
// Red
var b = new Module( { color: 'blue' } );
// Blue
```

---

**Edit**: Now also in [`underscore`](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) or [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#defaults)!

```
function Module(options){
    var actual = _.defaults(options || {}, {
         color: 'red'
    });
    console.info( actual.color );
}

var a = new Module();
// Red
var b = new Module( { color: 'blue' } );
// Blue
```

---

In Javascript ES6 you can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
function Module(options = {}){
    let defaults = {
        color: 'red'
    };
    let actual = Object.assign({}, defaults, options);
    console.info( actual.color );
}
```

Comment: The naming is kind of confusing ... you don't really want `defaults.color`, you want the actual option.

Comment: I did a minor style edit, changed `'color'` into `color` - I think it's more idiomatic js, no?

Comment: Edited the naming to make it a bit more apparent.

Comment: Late to the party, but the problem with object.assign is that it will copy the entire object in from "options". So if you have a deep nesting structure, it will not merge those options, it will overwrite them.

Comment: @LarryBud thats a good point. Deep nesting seems a bit out of scope of the original question though.

Comment: FWIW Lodash also has a `defaultsDeep` function I ended up using. I really wish default parameters would work many levels deep (`config.extraPropsForFields.defaultPropsForTextFields = { hasFloatingLabel: true; placeholder: ' ' }`

Answer (score 69):

Using the ES2018 [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) for object properties:

```
const defaults = { a: 1, b: 2 };

const ƒ = (given = {}) => {
  const options = { ...defaults, ...given };
  console.log(options);
};
```

Using ES6/ES2015 features, several more options are available.

Using destructuring assignment:

```
const { a = 1, b = 2 } = options;
```

You can also use destructuring function parameters:

```
const ƒ = ({a = 1, b = 2, c = 3} = {}) => {
   console.log({ a, b, c });
};
```

Using `Object.assign`:

```
options = Object.assign({}, defaults, options);
```

No dependencies!

Comment: this pattern is great, saves me a lot of real estate.  Though it should be noted that the assignment is shallow, not deep

Comment: Be careful! if your `options` input has a known key (e.g. `a`) mapped to `undefined`, you won't pick up the value for that property from your `defaults`

Answer (score 20):

To get default options without additional dependencies, I use the following pattern:

```
var my_function = function (arg1, arg2, options) {
    options = options || {};
    options.opt_a = options.hasOwnProperty('opt_a') ? options.opt_a : 'default_opt_a';
    options.opt_b = options.hasOwnProperty('opt_b') ? options.opt_b : 'default_opt_b';
    options.opt_c = options.hasOwnProperty('opt_c') ? options.opt_c : 'default_opt_b';


    // perform operation using options.opt_a, options.opt_b, etc.
};
```

Although a bit verbose, I find it easy to read, add/remove options and add defaults. When there are LOTS of options, a slightly more compact version is:

```
var my_function = function (arg1, arg2, options) {
    var default_options = {
        opt_a: 'default_opt_a',
        opt_b: 'default_opt_b',
        opt_c: 'default_opt_c'};

    options = options || {};
    for (var opt in default_options)
        if (default_options.hasOwnProperty(opt) && !options.hasOwnProperty(opt))
            options[opt] = default_options[opt];

    // perform operation using options.opt_a, options.opt_b, etc.
};
```

Comment: Also, I would like to point out that as of Oct 22 the accepted answer by ripper234 doesn't work correctly. In the code example opt_c and opt_d always have default_for_c and default_for_d, even if other values were present in the options object. Changing the ordering of the parameters to the logical OR fixes this (a || b vs b || a).

Answer (score 11):

And the more compact jQuery version:

```
function func(opts) {
    opts = $.extend({
        a: 1,
        b: 2
    }, opts);

    console.log(opts);
}

func();            // Object {a: 1, b: 2} 
func({b: 'new'});  // Object {a: 1, b: "new"}
```

Comment: Flaw with that is that your code now depends on jQuery to operate and if that is the only reason for using jQuery. You're adding a lot of unnecessary code on the client side by including jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

Using ES6 Spread Operator without using external libraries

```
function Example(opts) {
   let defaults = { foo: 1, bar: 2 }
   opts = { ...defaults, ...(opts || {}) }
   console.log(opts);
}

Example({ bar: 3, baz: 4 })

// { foo: 1, bar: 3, baz: 4 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do this in many consecutive functions, a way to standardize the process and speed it up is:

```
function setOpts (standard, user) {
  if (typeof user === 'object' {
    for (var key in user) {
      standard[key] = user[key];
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can just define your functions simply like this:

```
var example = function (options) {
  var opts = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c:3
  };
  setOpts(opts, options);
}
```

This way you only define one options object inside the function, which contains the default values.

If you want to put an extra check to [avoid prototype inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), the first function can be:

```
function setOpts (standard, user) {
  if (typeof user === 'object') {
    Object.keys(user).forEach(function (key) {
      standard[key] = user[key];
    });
  }
}
```

The latter case is not supported for: IE < 9, Chrome < 5, Firefox < 4, Safari < 5

(you can check the compatibility table [here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Object.keys))

---

Finally **ECMAScript 6** will bring us the best way to do this: [**default parameters**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters).

It will take a few months though before this is widely supported across browsers.

Comment: "t will take a few months though before this is widely supported across browsers.". I like your optimism. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to [ES6 with a stage 4 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) (such as with Babel) you can accomplish this with spread and destructuring assignment.

```js
const defaultPrintOptions = {
  fontName: "times",
  fontStyle: "normal",
  fontSize: 10,
  align: "left"
};

// Setting the null default isn't necessary but
// makes it clear that the parameter is optional.
// Could use {} but would create a new object
// each time the function is called.
function print(text, options = null) {
  let {
    fontName,
    fontStyle,
    fontSize,
    align
  } = {
    ...defaultPrintOptions,
    ...options
  };

  console.log(text, fontName, fontStyle, fontSize, align);
}

print("All defaults:");
print("Override some:", {
  fontStyle: "italic",
  align: "center"
});
print("Override all:", {
  fontName: "courier",
  fontStyle: "italic",
  fontSize: 24,
  align: "right"
});
```

This also works (but may create more objects):

```
function myFunction({ 
  text = "", 
  line = 0, 
  truncate = 100 
} = {}) {
  console.log(text, line, truncate);
}
```

(latter example from [David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/destructuring-function-arguments) - @wprl's answer also mentions this)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple and clean approach, hopefully, this helps someone:

```
function example(url, {title = false, check = false, wait = false} = {}){
  console.log('url: ', URL);
  console.log('title: ', title);
  console.log('check: ', check);
  console.log('wait: ', wait);
}

example('https://example.com', {wait: 20})
```

Here is the output of the code above:

```
url:  https://example.com
title:  false
check:  false
wait:  20
```

Comment: This is the best. Also in TypeScript, it would be something like this: `{title = false, check = false, wait = false}: {title: false | string, check: boolean, wait: false | number} = {}`

Answer (score 1):

```
      var mergeOptions = function mergeOptions(userOptions) {

        // Default options
        var options = {
            height: "100px",
            width: "100px" ,
            color: "blue"
        }

        if (userOptions) {
            Object.keys(userOptions).forEach(function (key) {
                options[key] = userOptions[key]
            })
        }

        return options;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is pretty straight way to merge options with defaults it has some disadvantages:

1. if you want to set conditional options with ternary operator - it will overwrite defaults even for `undefined` values:

   ```
   const options = {
     logging: isProduction ? 'none' : undefined
   };
   const defaults = {
     logging: 'verbose'
   }
   Object.assign({}, defaults, options); // {logging: undefined} !
   ```
2. if you provide incorrect option name - you will not be warned:

   ```
   const options = {
     loging: 'none' // typo
   };
   const defaults = {
     logging: 'verbose'
   }
   Object.assign({}, defaults, options); // {logging: 'verbose', loging: 'none'} !
   ```

To cover these cases I've created tiny [flat-options](https://github.com/vitalets/flat-options) package.
It does not overwrite defaults for `undefined` values:

```
const options = {
  logging: isProduction ? 'none' : undefined
};
const defaults = {
  logging: 'verbose'
}
flatOptions(options, defaults); // {logging: 'verbose'}
```

and warns for incorrect option names:

```
const options = {
  loging: 'none' // typo
};
const defaults = {
  logging: 'verbose'
}
flatOptions(options, defaults); // throws "Unknown option: loging."
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a new javascript syntax for easily setting defaults, logical assignment operators:

```js
// Super crazy this:
staticConfig.defaultPropsForFoo = 
  staticConfig.defaultPropsForFoo || {
    myDefault: 'props'
  }
// turns into:
staticConfig.defaultPropsForFoo ||= { myDefault: 'props' }
```

Also works with nullish operator if you prefer stricter boolean semantics:

```
staticConfig.defaultPropsForFoo ??= { myDefault: 'props' }
```

(Arguably we should always use `??=` version but it's also pretty new)

Also, I use default params all the time, but this syntax works inside of any destructuring assignment:

```js
const {
  defaultPropsForFoo = { myDefault: 'props' },
  ...restConfig
} = staticConfig
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeing all solutions, I prefer the way as following:

```js
function example(firstArgument, optional = {}) {
  const {
    a = 123, // default value
    b,
  } = optional;
  console.log(firstArgument, a, b);
}
```

And this way support multiple syntax to call:

```js
example(); // undefined 123 undefined
example("test"); // test 123 undefined
example("test", { a: 456 }); // test 456 undefined
example("test", { b: 456 }); // test 123 456
example("test", { a: 456, b: 123 }); // test 456 123
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for something like this (sorry for the late reply):

```
function foo(a, b, options) { 
    this.defaults = {
        x: 48, 
        y: 72,
        z: 35
    };
    for (var i in this.defaults) {
        if (options[i] != "undefined") { this.defaults[i] = options[i]; }
    }
    // more code...
}
```

edit: apologies, grabbed this from some old code... You should make sure to use the hasOwnProperty() method to make sure you don't iterate over everything on function.prototype

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: There's a typo here: you're checking if the options are the string `"undefined"` instead of really undefined (you probably left out a `typeof`, but `options[i] !== undefined` is good too if you're willing to assume that some bozo didn't redefine `undefined`).

Comment: For a working version of this pseudo-code, see [the answer by Rick Deckard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19525082/12534).