# Is there a way to variably name a function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I would like to variably assign a name to a new function, is this possible?

```
function returnFunctionWithName(str){
  return function(){
    return srt
  }
}

var x = returnFunctionWithName("hello")

console.log(x) // => [Function]
```

What I want is something like this: (this doesn't work)

```
function returnFunctionWithName(str){
  return function [str](){
    return srt
  }
}

var x = returnFunctionWithName("hello")

console.log(x) // => [Function: hello]
```

Just tried this too with no effect:

```
function returnFunctionWithName(str){
  var x = function(){
    return str
  }
  x.name = str
  return x
}

var x = returnFunctionWithName("hello")

console.log(x) // => [Function: hello]
```

Comment: Before anything else, explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: The question is a bit cryptic at the moment.  Can you describe what problem you're really trying to solve so rather than comment on your proposed solution, we can actually offer a solution to the real problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vfc99eg4/

Comment: @jfriend00 The code above is what I'm trying to do. I have a function that returns an anonymous function and I'd like to name it before I return it.

Comment: But why do you want a *dynamic* name? A function with a fixed body surely needs only one name.

Comment: @Tomalak not in the case I'm using it for, sorry I don't have more context.

Comment: @ThomasReggi - you are describing your attempted solution to your problem.  You are not describing the actual problem that makes you think you need a solution like this.  It seems unlikely to us that you need multiple names for the exact same function or that whatever issue you have couldn't be solved a completely different way.  You will ALWAYS give yourself a better chance of getting helpful answers if you describe the actual real problem, not just issues with your solution.  This is known as [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @jfriend00 Right now I'm passing function(s) as arguments into functions as [Object methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623026/what-do-you-call-an-object-with-functions-in-it) which is the right way to do this. I need the functions to be named for the consuming function to work. I was hoping to skip that step and just pass in or assign names directly to functions.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm literally sitting in bed because I can't go to sleep, thinking of different ways to push the language.

Comment: Why does a function have to have a name for the consuming function to work?  That part has me baffled.  If you just want a unique identifier for a function, you can always just create your own property on the function since functions are objects that can have custom properties.

Comment: Your right I could have added properties to the function for metadata like `name`. However then I'd have to invent my own schema for how that data is treated / consumed. Rather then inventing that I wanted to know the limitation of the language. Now that I know naming a function like this isn't feasible (not messing with `exec`), I can use Object Methods or attach properties to the function.

Comment: I really wish people would let questions be instead of trying to find the 'Z'. Even if this doesn't solve the 'Y', *the 'X' was clearly asked about*. Answer it or (after a simple comment aside) leave it well-enough alone..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can technically set a function's `name` property as follows:

```
Object.defineProperty(theFunction, 'name', {
    get: function() { 
        return 'NewFunctionName'; 
    }
});
```

However, I don't know if this solves your problem, as in my [quick tests](http://jsbin.com/quyasaxona/edit?js,console) this didn't actually render the expected name when `console.log`'ing the function.

The reason that `x.name = str` doesn't work is that `Function#name` [isn't writable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name). It *is*, however, "Configurable", which means you can mess with it via `Object.defineProperty()`.

Comment: Cool idea! This is giving me `TypeError: Cannot redefine property: name` in nodejs.

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't apply to many environments... Some protect the name property allowing no modification whatsoever.

Comment: Hmm, just verified that error in node.js as well.... so, what @FuzzicalLogic said. :\

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the `name` property, although it's been around in most engines for ages, wasn't standardized until ES6, so I guess whichever version of V8 is being used in the versions of Node we're testing against haven't implemented the Configurable requirement yet.

Comment: I was previously testing in Node v0.10.38. I just verified that it still doesn't work as desired in v0.12.7, either.

Answer (score -1):

The only cross-browser way I have found to do what you are asking is actually very unsafe in many circumstances... So, with care, the answer is below.

```
 function makeNewFunction(name) {
    return eval('(function(){ return function ' + name + '() {' +
        ' // code as a string' +
        + '}; }) ();');
 }
```

I had to use something like this awhile ago using a technique I call evilclassing.